# opacity background at bottom of div not attaching properly

Tags: html, css, opacity

I'm trying to create a clickable image that has text running across the bottom with a background behind the text set to half opacity. Quite common in a lot of websites. I have this working other than a bottom lip running the length of the image poking out below the text background. It seems to be coming from the `li` containing the image and anchor. I've searched online and tried several ways to remove it but without any success.

How can I get the background color for my text to fit neatly to the bottom of my image ?

```
<ul id='main-aside-buddhaImgs'>
    <li>
        <div class='titleCont'>
            <a href='#'><img src='images/squarebuddha.jpg' alt='budda' height='120' width='120'/>
                <span>title</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
```

```
ul#main-aside-buddhaImgs {
    float:left;
}

ul#main-aside-buddhaImgs li {
    float:left;
    padding:12px 15px;
}

ul#main-aside-buddhaImgs li div.titleCont {
    position:relative;
}

ul#main-aside-buddhaImgs li a {
    display:block;
}

ul#main-aside-buddhaImgs li a span{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    color:#fc6;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #300;
    background: rgba(51,0,0,.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your bottom attribute for ul#main-aside-buddhaImgs li a span to 4px

```
ul#main-aside-buddhaImgs li a span{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    color:#fc6;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #300;
    background: rgba(51,0,0,.5);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kr5QP/

Comment: Oh great! What was happening there, where did the 4px come from ?

Comment: Your `a` is 4px taller than your image, and the absolute positioning is based on the anchor element

Comment: Ah I see, cheers. Without wanting to go on. Why is the anchor element 4px taller than the image ?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but the div and li element outside of it are too